# While loop in batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, while-loop

Here is what I want, inside the `BACKUPDIR`, I want to execute `cscript /nologo c:\deletefile.vbs %BACKUPDIR%` until number of files inside the folder is greater than 21(`countfiles` holds it).
Here is my code:

```
@echo off
SET BACKUPDIR=C:\test
for /f %%x in ('dir %BACKUPDIR% /b ^| find /v /c "::"') do set countfiles=%%x

for %countfiles% GTR 21 (
cscript /nologo c:\deletefile.vbs %BACKUPDIR%
set /a countfiles-=%countfiles%
)
```

Comment: So what is your question? Does this batch work or is your problem that it's broken?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

```
set /a countfiles-=%countfiles%
```

This will set countfiles to 0. I think you want to decrease it by 1, so use this instead:

```
set /a countfiles-=1
```

I'm not sure if the for loop will work, better try something like this:

```
:loop
cscript /nologo c:\deletefile.vbs %BACKUPDIR%
set /a countfiles-=1
if %countfiles% GTR 21 goto loop
```

Answer (score 68):

A `while` loop can be simulated in `cmd.exe` with:

```
:still_more_files
    if %countfiles% leq 21 (
        rem change countfile here
        goto :still_more_files
    )
```

For example, the following script:

```
    @echo off
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
    set /a "x = 0"

:more_to_process
    if %x% leq 5 (
        echo %x%
        set /a "x = x + 1"
        goto :more_to_process
    )

    endlocal
```

outputs:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
```

For your particular case, I would start with the following. Your initial description was a little confusing. I'm assuming you want to delete files in that directory until there's 20 or less:

```
    @echo off
    set backupdir=c:\test

:more_files_to_process
    for /f %%x in ('dir %backupdir% /b ^| find /v /c "::"') do set num=%%x
    if %num% gtr 20 (
        cscript /nologo c:\deletefile.vbs %backupdir%
        goto :more_files_to_process
    )
```

Comment: exaclty what you are saying, however theres an issue that it goes into an infinite loop, seems like counfiles should be decreased inside the loop, such as set /a "countfiles = countfiles-1" but it doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: @Hellnar, countfiles is set to the real value again by virtue of the fact the for-statement that calculates it is *inside* the loop. I did it that way since it wasn't clear how many files your VBScript file was deleting.

Comment: If you have an infinite loop, replace "@echo off" with "::@echo off" and re-run the script. That will output the commands as they're executed and you will see what countfiles is being set to.

Comment: It works when you name it `while`, is there any reason you named it `while1`?

Comment: @Noumenon: just because I tend to have multiple `while` loops in code. In reality, you could pretty much call it whatever you wanted. What I *will* do is make it a little more verbose to clarify intent.

Comment: Thanks, that would be a gotcha if I named them all the same. Can you give an example of a helpful verbose label name?

Answer (score 16):

### I have a trick for doing this!

I came up with this method because while on the CLI, it's not possible to use the methods provided in the other answers here and it had always bugged me.

### I call this the "Do Until Break" or "Infinite" Loop:

Basic Example

```cmd
FOR /L %L IN (0,0,1) DO @(
 ECHO. Counter always 0, See "%L" = "0" - Waiting a split second&ping -n 1 127.0.0.1>NUL )
```

**This is truly an infinite loop!**

This is useful for monitoring something in a `CMD` window, and allows you to use `CTRL`+`C` to break it when you're done.

**Want to Have a counter?**

Either use `SET /A` OR You can modify the `FOR /L` Loop to do the counting and still be infinite (Note, BOTH of these methods have a 32bit integer overflow)

`SET /A` Method:

```cmd
FOR /L %L IN (0,0,1) DO @(
 SET /A "#+=1"&ECHO. L Still equals 0, See "%L = 0"!  - Waiting a split second &ping -n 1 127.0.0.1>NUL  )
```

Native `FOR /L` Counter:

```cmd
FOR /L %L IN (-2147483648,1,2147483648) DO @(
 ECHO.Current value of L: %L - Waiting a split second &ping -n 1 127.0.0.1>NUL  )
```

Counting Sets of 4294967295 and Showing Current Value of L:

```cmd
FOR /L %L IN (1,1,2147483648) DO @(
 (
  IF %L EQU 0 SET /A "#+=1">NUL
 )&SET /A "#+=0"&ECHO. Sets of 4294967295 - Current value of L: %L - Waiting a split second &ping -n 1 127.0.0.1>NUL )
```

**However, what if:**

- You're interested in reviewing the output of the monitor, and concerned that I will pass the 9999 line buffer limit before I check it after it has completed.
- You'd like to take some additional actions once the Thing I am monitoring is finished.

For this, I determined how to use a couple methods to break the `FOR` Loop prematurely effectively turning it into a "`DO WHILE`" or "`DO UNTIL`" Loop, which is otherwise sorely lacking in CMD.

NOTE:  Most of the time a loop will continue to iterate past the condition you checked for, often this is a wanted behavior, but not in our case.

### Turn the "infinite Loop" into a "`DO WHILE`" / "`DO UNTIL`" Loop

UPDATE: Due to wanting to use this code in CMD Scripts (and have them persist!) as well as CLI, and on thinking if there might be a "more Correct" method to achieve this I recommend using the New method!

**New Method** (Can be used inside CMD Scripts without exiting the script):

```cmd
FOR /F %%A IN ('
  CMD /C "FOR /L %%L IN (0,1,2147483648) DO @( ECHO.%%L & IF /I %%L EQU 10 ( exit /b  ) )"
') DO @(
  ECHO %%~A
)
```

At CLI:

```cmd
FOR /F %A IN ('
  CMD /C "FOR /L %L IN (0,1,2147483648) DO @( ECHO.%L & IF /I %L EQU 10 ( exit /b  ) )"
') DO @(
  ECHO %~A
)
```

**Original Method** (Will work on CLI just fine, but will kill a script.)

```cmd
FOR /L %L IN (0,1,2147483648) DO @(
  ECHO.Current value of L: %L - Waiting a split second &ping -n 1 127.0.0.1>NUL&(
    IF /I %L EQU 10 (
      ECHO.Breaking the Loop! Because We have matched the condition!&DIR >&0
    )
  )
) 2>NUL
```

### Older Post Stuff

Through chance I had hit upon some ways to exit loops prematurely that did not close the CMD prompt when trying to do other things which gave me this Idea.

### NOTE:

While `ECHO.>&3 >NUL` had worked for me in some scenarios, I have played with this off and on over the years and found that `DIR >&0 >NUL` was much more consistent.

I am re-writing this answer from here forward to use that method instead as I recently found the old note to myself to use this method instead.

### Edited Post with better Method Follows:

```cmd
DIR >&0 >NUL
```

The >NUL is optional, I just prefer not to have it output the error.

I prefer to match inLine when possible, as you can see in this sanitized example of a Command I use to monitor LUN Migrations on our VNX.

```cmd
for /l %L IN (0,0,1) DO @(
   ECHO.& ECHO.===========================================& (
     [VNX CMD] | FINDSTR /R /C:"Source LU Name" /C:"State:" /C:"Time " || DIR >&0 >NUL
   ) & Ping -n 10 1.1.1.1 -w 1000>NUL )
```

Also, I have another method I found in that note to myself which I just re-tested to confirm works just as well at the CLI as the other method.

Apparently, when I first posted here I posted an older iteration I was playing with instead of the two newer ones which work better:

**In this method, we use `EXIT /B`** to exit the For Loop, but we don't want to exit the CLI so we wrap it in a CMD session:

```cmd
FOR /F %A IN ('CMD /C "FOR /L %L IN (0,1,10000000) DO @( ECHO.%L & IF /I %L EQU 10 ( exit /b  ) )" ') DO @(ECHO %~A)
```

Because the loop itself happens in the CMD session, we can use EXIT /B to exit the iteration of the loop without losing our CMD Session, and without waiting for the loop to complete, much the same as with the other method.

I would go so far as to say that this method is likely the "intended" method for the sort of scenario where you want to break a for loop at the CLI, as using CMD session is also the only way to get Delayed expansion working at the CLI for your loops, and the behavior and such behavior is clearly an intended workflow to leave a CMD session.

IE: Microsoft clearly made an intentional effort to have CMD Exit /B For loops behave this way, while the "Intended" way of doing this, as my other method, relies on having accidentally created just the right error to kick you out of the loop without letting the loop finish processing, which I only happenstantially discovered, and seems to only reliably work when using the DIR command which is fairly strange.

**So that said, I think it's probably a better practice to use Method 2:**

```cmd
FOR /F %A IN ('CMD /C "FOR /L %L IN (0,1,10000000) DO @( ECHO.%L & IF /I %L EQU 10 ( exit /b  ) )" ') DO @(ECHO %~A)
```

**Although I suspect Method 1 is going to be slightly faster:**

```cmd
FOR /L %L IN (0,1,10000000) DO @( ECHO.%L & IF /I %L EQU 10 ( DIR >&) >NUL ) )
```

**And in either case, both should allow DO-While loops as you need for your purposes.**

Comment: Loops like For /L %L in (0,1, BigNumber) or infinite loops like For /L %L in (0,0,1) are extremely inefficient.

Comment: @prampe A) `For /L %_ IN (0,1,2147483648)  DO [something] `AND  `For /L %_ IN (0)  DO [something] ` (or `For /L %_ IN (0,0,1)  DO [something] ` ) Are all Infinite loops.  (The older entries at the end with large numbers were a copy paste artifact.)  That said, wirhout even getting into a debate with you about "what loop method is best" -- This is the Only Method which works directly and natively on the CLI.  In addition, Infinite loops which are waiting for a seperate process to complete and then exit the loop will need a timeout to not burn CPU cycles needlessly regardless.

Answer (score 10):

```
@echo off

set countfiles=10

:loop

set /a countfiles -= 1

echo hi

if %countfiles% GTR 0 goto loop

pause
```

on the first "set countfiles" the 10 you see is the amount it will loop 
the echo hi is the thing you want to loop

...i'm 5 years late

Answer (score 4):

It was very useful for me i have used in the following way to add user in active directory:

```sh
:: This file is used to automatically add list of user to activedirectory
:: First ask for username,pwd,dc details and run in loop
:: dsadd user cn=jai,cn=users,dc=mandrac,dc=com -pwd `1q`1q`1q`1q

@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set /a "x = 1"
set /p lent="Enter how many Users you want to create : "
set /p Uname="Enter the user name which will be rotated with number ex:ram then ram1 ..etc : "
set /p DcName="Enter the DC name ex:mandrac : "
set /p Paswd="Enter the password you want to give to all the users : "

cls

:while1

if %x% leq %lent% (

    dsadd user cn=%Uname%%x%,cn=users,dc=%DcName%,dc=com -pwd %Paswd%
    echo User %Uname%%x% with DC %DcName% is created
    set /a "x = x + 1"
    goto :while1
)

endlocal
```