# Create X number of directories using batch script

Tags: batch-file, directory, mkdir, createfile

I am currently trying to write a quick batch script which will loop 1 through X and create a directory with an empty .txt file.

Here is what I have written so far:

```
set x = 10

:DoUntil

MkDir "Test Location %x%"
echo. 2>"Test Location %x%\EmptyFile.txt"
set x -= 1

IF x > 0 goto DoUntil
```

%x% isn't writing out 1,2,3... in each loop and the file isn't being created because the folder doesn't exist.

Can anyone help so that I can fix this script to have the following directories and files created?

```
Test Folder 1\EmptyFile.txt
Test Folder 2\EmptyFile.txt
Test Folder 3\EmptyFile.txt
Test Folder 4\EmptyFile.txt
Test Folder 5\EmptyFile.txt
Test Folder 6\EmptyFile.txt
Test Folder 7\EmptyFile.txt
Test Folder 8\EmptyFile.txt
Test Folder 9\EmptyFile.txt
Test Folder 10\EmptyFile.txt
```

I am open for a PowerShell implementation or something better if you have a suggestion. It's to help a QA person test a File Pickup service which will go out and collect files from specific directories all over the network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Powershell

```
foreach($i in 1..100)
{
    md "Test Folder $i" -force | out-null #or New-Item

    Set-Content -Path (join-path "Test Folder $i" "EmptyFile.txt") -Value $null

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to: [While loop in batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788473/while-loop-in-batch/1788487#1788487)

```
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set /a "x = 0"
:while1
    if %x% leq 10 (
        echo %x%
        MkDir "Test Location %x%"
        echo. 2>"Test Location %x%\EmptyFile.txt"
        set /a "x = x + 1"
        goto :while1
    )
endlocal
```

Comment: Thanks worked perfectly and if I could accept 2 answers I'd accept yours and @mikeblake's