# How to continuously execute an application with CMD?

Tags: shell, cmd, execute

I need to execute a synchronizing application continuously with a batch file. What I want to do is something like:

```
while true
   execute application
   sleep 1 minute
end while
```

Can this be done with CMD?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See [this question about while-loop-in-batch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788473/while-loop-in-batch)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using pure batch you could do this:

```
:LOOP
yourprogram.exe
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 61 >NUL
goto :LOOP
```

This means you don't have to install any other programs or create more scripts. It might not be pretty but it works! I have pinged 61 times as pinging the loopback seems to create a delayed second.

Answer (score 1):

Download [unixutils for win32](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/). In here, you will find **sleep.exe**. Put it somewhere in your path. (frex, in c:\windows)

Then, you can build a batch file similar to this

```
echo off
:here    
sleep 60s
echo Exec app
rem your app goes here
goto here
```