# How to write in windows bat equivalent to shell

Tags: windows, batch-file

Currently my shell script shows as below and I need to write equivalent in 
windows bat I am new to this tried little bit but not sure it is correct. Please help

Shell script:

```
 ./SetDate.sh $1
 until [[ $currentDate -eq $endDate ]] ; do

while read myline
do
    currentDate=$myline
done < currentDate.txt

    echo "The current date being processed is: " $currentDate 

# Invoke one day activity 
./OneDay.sh $currentDate

export ReturnCode=$?
if  [ ${ReturnCode} -ne 0 ];then
     echo "Running jobs failed. For more details see log files."
fi

# Go to the next day
./GetDate.sh
 done
```

Tried half the way in windows but not sure. Please help on this equivalent in windows bat.

```
until [[ %currentDate% EQ %endDate ]] ; do 

while read myline; 
do 
    currentDate = %myline% 
done <<currentDate.txt 

call OneDayActivity.bat %currentDate% 
set returnCode=%ERRORLEVEL% 
IF "%returnCode%" NEQ "0" ( 
  echo "Running jobs failed. For more details see log files." 
) 
call GetDate.bat 
:EOF
```

Thanks

Comment: You should show your translated part

Comment: Hi please find my translated part not sure correct please help me on thisuntil [[ %currentDate% EQ %endDate ]] ; do

 while read myline; do
    currentDate = %myline%

  done <<currentDate.txt


call OneDayActivity.bat %currentDate%

set returnCode=%ERRORLEVEL%
IF "%returnCode%" NEQ "0"(

 echo "Running jobs failed. For more details see log files."
)

call GetDate.bat

:EOF

Comment: The key part of your question seems to be _“How to write `while` or `until` in batch file?”_ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788473/while-loop-in-batch

Comment: Hi yes I am still confusion how to write while or until. Please help me on this.

Comment: There is no native `while` nor `until` in `cmd`/batch; so you have to work around this using `if` and `goto`; the logic how to combine that should not be too difficult...